# Why doesn't qDebug output anything after clicking the button?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I'm trying to implement one thing with signals and slots, and the problem arises that after pressing the button nothing happens, although the path to the file should be displayed. The button is made using the Qt Designer.

```cpp
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "model.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
~Controller();

public slots:
    void onFileSelected(const QString& filePath);

private:
    // Model* model = nullptr;
    MainWindow* view = nullptr;
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

controller.cpp:

```cpp
#include "controller.h"

Controller::Controller(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    // model = new Model(this);
    view = new MainWindow();

    connect(view, &MainWindow::fileSelected, this, &Controller::onFileSelected);
}

Controller::~Controller()
{
    // delete model;
    delete view;
}

void Controller::onFileSelected(const QString& filePath)
{
     qDebug() << "File selected: " << filePath;
     // qDebug() << model->getHeaders();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```cpp
ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
   ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void fileSelected(const QString& filePath);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtCharts>

using namespace QtCharts;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "choose file", QDir::currentPath());

    emit fileSelected(filePath);
}
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setMinimumSize(1200, 900);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

If you try to send the signal to the same file it was sent from, everything works fine!

Comment: Where and how do you create an instance of `Controller`? Show a [mcve]. I suspect you are creating an instance of `MainWindow` outside of and independent from `Controller`. The instance where you click the button is not the same instance that `Controller` connected its slot to.

Comment: thats all my code

Comment: That can't be. There's no code that actually creates an instance of `Controller` or `MainWindow`, and shows the window on the screen. At least, there must be `main` function.

Comment: The line `view = new MainWindow();` is in the constructor of `Controller`. Before this line is executed, some piece of code must actually create an instance of `Controller`, so its constructor would actually run. But no part of the code shown creates a `Controller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) said:

> I suspect you are creating an instance of `MainWindow` outside of and independent from `Controller`. The instance where you click the button is not the same instance that `Controller` connected its slot to.

You should do the opposite of what you're doing, instantiate a `Controller` in `MainWindow`, and connect signals to slots there.

Example:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Controller *controller = new Controller;

    connect(this, &
MainWindow::fileSelected, controller, &Controller::onFileSelected);
}
```

And remove `MainWindow` object from `Controller`'s class.